# Login to Amazon cloud PC in SaaS courses from Stanford

Tags: amazon-web-services, saas

I try to learn following courses and set up VM on Amazon according to instruction.
http://beta.saasbook.info/bookware-vm-instructions
According to this courses I should get of full value VM (with X server etc) but I just see as connect to it by SSH.

Does anybody configure such machine to get graphical UI?

https://class.coursera.org/saas/class/